# Futuristic agent stuck in past, runs off with own mother

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, space

Pretty sure this was a full novel from the 80s. Set in the future with spaceships, a special agent has a traumatic memory of someone taking away his mother and being abandoned.

Somehow on a mission he ends up in the past. I think there was an entire adventure plot with a villain, that I just don't remember.

But the kicker is that he gets romantically involved with a woman and then tries to save her during a calamity, but doesn't have time to get her son. He then realizes who she is, and that he caused his own trauma.

Comment: Reminds me of a faded/bent memory of "All You Zombies" by Robert A. Heinlein -- except that was a short story, and the time traveler *was* his mother (as well as his father).

Comment: Yes, it also reminded me of those stories as well. But this was more of a special agent adventure that culminated with him causing his own childhood trauma.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon More like Heinlein's "Time Enough for Love" where Lazurus Long did get involved with his mother, and was injured badly at the end in one the World Wars, and his clone 'sisters' rescue him at the end. He was there undercover (sort of)